# paging and pre-paging technique used in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to know what's the current page swapping algorithm used in Linux kernel. Also, is there any pre-paging technique used in Linux kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that an LRU(Least Recently Used) approach is taken.

The long answer is found [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand013.html) with references to other sources as well..

Comment: The short answer fails to answer the second question: "is there any pre-paging technique used in Linux kernel?"